# unexpected behavior of overloaded operator "<<" c++

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

I wrote a simple program to demonstrate the use of overloaded operator << in c++. According to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=msvc-160, I tried writing my own code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Date
{
private:
    std::string str;
public:
    Date(int x) : str(5, 'x'){}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Date& dt){
        os << dt.str;
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Date dt(6);
    std::cout << dt;
}
```

This code worked correctly as it printed "xxxxx" to the console. However when I remove the argument of the constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Date
{
private:
    std::string str;
public:
    Date() : str(5, 'x'){}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Date& dt){
        os << dt.str;
        return os;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Date dt();
    std::cout << dt;
}
```

, I got "1" printed to the console. I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: thats a nasty incarnation of the most vexing parse (plus unfortunate overload resolution)

Comment: `Date dt();` is a function named `dt` with no arguments and the return type `Date`. Alternatives that will create a default constructed `Date` are `Date dt;`, `Date dt{};` or `auto dt = Date();`.

Comment: use  Date dt{} instead

Comment: Clearly in the second example you are using the default constructor `Date()` which you have not defined, so the compiler synthetises it as creating an empty `Date` object. And in the first example, the output would be `xxxxx` regardless of the argument you give to the object `dt` you create in `main()`.

Comment: @Giogre there is a definition for the default constructor in the second example, but `Date dt();` is not calling the default constructor

Comment: Thank you Giogre, your explanation is clear enough.

Comment: @Sao_Si sorry to say it, but the explanation in Giogres comment is plain wrong

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 `Date dt();` is a forward declaration effectively. I did read `Date dt{}`.

Comment: @Sao_Si -- Define a function called `dt` that has no arguments and returns a `Date`.  You see the issue now?  That function declaration looks exactly like `Date dt();` -- so what is the compiler going to use?  If it looks like a function, the compiler assumes it's a function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh I see. At first I thought that the compiler saw the declaration Date dt(); as a new object. Thanks for your illustration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with following:

```
    int main()
    {
        Date dt;
        std::cout << dt;
    }
```

Which compiler you are using? Microsoft C++ compiler report a linking error with your main function without arg i.e. `Date dt();`

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class Date __cdecl dt(void)" (?dt@@YA?AVDate@@XZ)`

Comment: Thanks, finally it worked. I'm using gcc for linux. Thanks again

Comment: good, if it worked pls accept the answer.

Comment: @mkag Why not explain why `Date dt();` is not correct?  Answers should come with explanations as to the cause of the issue.